# Find difference between list and set

Tags: python, list, set

I am trying to find differences between MongoDB records. After performing my queries, I end up with a set of unique results (by applying `set()`).

Now, I want to compare a new extraction with the set that I just defined to see if there are any new additions to the record.

What I have done now is the following:

```
unique_documents = set([str(i) for i in dict_of_uniques[my_key]])
all_documents = [str(i) for i in (dict_of_all_docs[my_key])]
```

Basically I am trying to compare the string version of a dict among the two variables.

I have several approaches, among which `unique_documents.difference(all_documents)`, but it keeps out returning an empty set. I know for a fact that the all_documents variable contains two new entries in the record. I would like to know which ones are they.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

If `all_documents` is the set with new elements that you want to get as the result, then you need to reverse the order of the arguments to the `difference` method.

```
unique_documents = set([str(i) for i in dict_of_uniques[my_key]])
all_documents = set([str(i) for i in (dict_of_all_docs[my_key])])
```

```
all_documents.difference(unique_documents)
```

See how the order matters:

```
>>> x = set([1,2,3])
>>> y = set([3,4,5])
>>> x.difference(y)
{1, 2}
>>> y.difference(x)
{4, 5}
```

`difference` gives you the elements of the *first* set that are not present in the *second* set.

If you want to see things that were either added *or* removed, you can `symmetric_difference`. This function is described as "symmetric" because it gives the same results regardless of argument order.

```
>>> x.symmetric_difference(y)
{1, 2, 4, 5}
>>> y.symmetric_difference(x)
{1, 2, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell without a description of the dictionary structure but your code seems to be comparing single keys only.  If you want to compare the content of both dictionaries, you need to get all the values:

```
currentData = set( str(rec) for rec in dict_of_all_docs.values() )
changedKeys = [k for k,value in dict_of_fetched.items() if str(value) not in currentData]
```

This doesn't seem very efficient though but without more information on the data structure, it is hard to make a better suggestion. If your records can already matched by a dictionary key, you probably don't need to use a set at all. A simple loop should do.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than `unique_documents.difference(all_documents)` use `all_documents.difference(unique_documents)`

[More on Python Sets](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-set-difference/)